# Using ExtractTextPlugin for Webpack, how do you not extract css and create an empty file with a flag?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader, extract-text-plugin

Basically I want to extract css in production, but I want to leave it in the JavaScript file in development mode.

This is so I can have the sourcemap working which shows the sass files used.

I want to be able to have:

```
<link href="~/dist/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/js/manifest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/js/css.js"></script>
```

Documentation is a bit thin on the ground.

So in dev mode `site.css` will be empty and won't cause an error like it would if it didn't exist. `css.js` will be used for style and source mapping.

In production mode `css.js` will exist but just not do anything because the css is extracted. This means the css will load nice and quickly and minified in `site.css` but have no mapping.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was this:
Installed and required webpack-create-file-plugin
Created the css directory with a .empty file in it because the directory must exist.

This is generally how I have done it:

```
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/site.css");
const sassOptions = removeEmpty([
    ifNotProd({
        loader: "style-loader"
    }),
    {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
            sourceMap: ifNotProd()
        }
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
            outputStyle: ifProd("compressed", "expanded"),
            sourceMap: ifNotProd()
        }
    }
]);
```

The sass rule looks like this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ifProd(extractSass.extract({
        use: sassOptions,
        fallback: "style-loader"
    }), sassOptions)
}
```

Added to plugins `ifNotProd(new CreateFilePlugin({files: ["css/site.css"]}))` and `ifProd(extractSass)`